# caffeinate under lion 10.7.4

Tags: macos, terminal, sleep-wake

today i'm trying to use the typical 'caffeinate -t 1000' on terminal and get this output:

Gabrieles-MacBook:~ black$ caffeinate -t 1000

-bash: caffeinate: command not found

So i read the man page and i saw the path was /usr/bin/ and no binary of caffeinate there.
What can i do? I tried caffeine and owly from the appstore with no results. I don't understand.
I used it every day when i had mountain lion or el captain. Now i did a downgrade on macbook because el cap is too slow and now i have lion 10.7.4

Thanks, Gabriele.

Comment: What happens if you use the fully qualified pathname? `/usr/bin/caffeinate` If that works and `caffeinate` by itself doesn't, then you have a problem with your `PATH` variable. Check and see if `/usr/bin` is in your `PATH` using: `echo $PATH`

Comment: What do you get when you issue the command `find / -name caffeinate`?  When you did the downgrade, did you wipe your drive?

Comment: Sorry guys, i enabled the notification when i get registered but it doesn't worked!

@user3439894 i did /usr/bin/caffeinate -t 5454 and get:
-bash: /usr/bin/caffeinate: No such file or directory

Comment: @blackfromabove, Did you try the `find` command suggested by Allan and did it find it?

Comment: @Allan
Yes man from the disk utility on lion fresh installation.
My output is:
find: /dev/fd/3: Not a directory
find: /dev/fd/4: Not a directory

Anyway guys just googling better found this from osxdaily:
To use the caffeinate command you’ll need to be running a fairly modern version of OS X, as the feature was introduced in 10.8 Mountain Lion and persists through 10.9 Mavericks, and into 10.10 Yosemite.

And googling yet better than before found this:
pmset noidle

That force to stay awake! Same behavior so so, in any case this works and i'll use it!
Thanks to all!

Comment: @user3439894 that's it!

Answer (score 2):

"To use the caffeinate command you’ll need to be running a fairly modern version of OS X, as the feature was introduced in 10.8 Mountain Lion and persists through 10.9 Mavericks, and into 10.10 Yosemite.
Heads up to MacWorld for the tip."
Source: http://osxdaily.com/2012/08/03/disable-sleep-mac-caffeinate-command/

Alternative to caffeinate:
http://lifehacker.com/5767991/how-to-force-your-mac-to-stay-awake-indefinitely-via-the-command-line
Thus work for me!